# Dodge Journey (2103): repair Bluetooth or replace infotainment system?

Tags: dodge, bluetooth, journey, infotainment

I have a 2013 Dodge Journey, and the Uconnect infotainment system is not connecting on Bluetooth any longer. As you can see in the picture, it shows the Bluetooth connect "button" but does nothing when you press it. Is there a repair for this that anyone knows?

Also, is it possible to upgrade or replace these systems with an aftermarket system. This one is old, and I'd like to replace it with one that supports AppleCarplay or Android Auto.
If you replace them, do you end up replacing the screen also and just connecting a new computer, or does the screen need to be replaced also? If that's the case, is there a standard size and fit, so I don't end up with a lot of big gaps in my dashboard?[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems to be a “delete and repost” - not popular on here.

Comment: @SolarMike what do you mean by delete and repost? I've posted on answer as I think this question is a good fit for the site, but will be happy to remove it if the question is in bad faith.

Comment: @psaxton I seem to remember reading it a few days ago - same pics anyway then it disappeared to come back again. If it only needed editing then edit the original.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a standard double din size radio with a trim bezel in front of it. You should be able to pick up three items to upgrade it. You will need a new stereo head, an adapter to connect from  the Dodge harness(es) to the new stereos plug(s) and a trim kit for your vehicle (2013 Dodge Journey). Recommending specific products is off topic, but you should be able to find each of these items through your local car stereo shop.

If you're not comfortable disassembling  your dashboard, consider going to a car stereo shop and letting them do the installation. It's not typically very expensive especially if you are already buying the equipment through them.

If you choose to buy online, be sure to make sure the parts you get are compatible with each other.

Comment: My standard double din has parallel sides, so I am not so sure.

Comment: There is a plastic bezel trimming the front of the actual stereo. If you remove that, I'm sure it will look like a standard double din. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bdn9DBHUTXI